# How to use image from sprite with "img src=" in checkout button

Tags: sprite, css-sprites

I'm trying to implement a sprite, so the "buy-now-black.jpg" image in this code

```
<div class="price-footer">
<a href="https://gumroad.com/l/12criticalthings?wanted=true"><img src="img/buy-now-black.jpg" width="131" height="134" alt="buy now"></a></div>
```

switches to an identical image within a sprite.

The html for that image is

```
<div class="buy-now-black"></div>
```

but I can't figure out how to reference it within the buy button code.

Here's the CSS related to the sprite:

```
    .two-choices-blue-txt, .12-critical-things-logo-simple, .the-new-york-times-vector-logo, .paypal-checkout-1-digital, .buy-now-black,
.buy-now-blue, .buy-now-dark-gray, .buy-now-green, .paypal-checkout-1-print, .paypal-checkout-5-print,
.usnews-n-ww-logo, .today-show, .savvy-senior-110w, .ducttape-logo, .john-jantsch
{ display: inline-block; background: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/bothsider_bucket/4_1422626839_0.png') no-repeat; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -9999px; text-align: left; }

.two-choices-blue-txt { background-position: -2px -0px; width: 348px; height: 252px; }
.12-critical-things-logo-simple { background-position: -2px -254px; width: 276px; height: 31px; }
.the-new-york-times-vector-logo { background-position: -2px -287px; width: 141px; height: 20px; }
.paypal-checkout-1-digital { background-position: -145px -287px; width: 133px; height: 196px; }
.buy-now-black { background-position: -2px -309px; width: 131px; height: 134px; }
.buy-now-blue { background-position: -2px -445px; width: 131px; height: 134px; }
.buy-now-dark-gray { background-position: -135px -485px; width: 131px; height: 134px; }
.buy-now-green { background-position: -2px -581px; width: 131px; height: 134px; }
.paypal-checkout-1-print { background-position: -135px -621px; width: 127px; height: 176px; }
.paypal-checkout-5-print { background-position: -2px -717px; width: 127px; height: 176px; }
.usnews-n-ww-logo { background-position: -131px -799px; width: 111px; height: 27px; }
.today-show { background-position: -131px -828px; width: 111px; height: 40px; }
.savvy-senior-110w { background-position: -131px -870px; width: 110px; height: 51px; }
.ducttape-logo { background-position: -2px -895px; width: 108px; height: 50px; }
.john-jantsch { background-position: -280px -254px; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
```

Source for the html, css and sprite image is spritegen.com (I have no relationship with them)

Comment: your sprites are backgrounds, and will be hidden behind the `<img>` you've got inside the div. your css would also have to HIDE the image so the background could be made visible.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB. I'm a beginner, but I'll hunt for an article so I can learn more about how to make changes based on your comment.

Comment: Idea: is there a way to take a specific part of a sprite image and define or name it in the code as if it were a regular uploaded image (e.g. img/buy-now-black.png), in order to enable "img src=" functionality in the html, while still enjoying the benefits of using a sprite?

Comment: `<img>` tags don't support that kind of positioning of their image, but you can wrap the image with a `<div>` and position the `<img>` tag itself within the div, to get the same effect.